# 'localtime' api doesn't consider the local timezone, instead uses Pacific Time Zone

Tags: c, localtime, crt

The documentation for [localtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf12f0hc.aspx) notes the following:

> localtime corrects for the local time zone if the user first sets the global environment variable TZ. When TZ is set, three other environment variables (_timezone, _daylight, and _tzname) are automatically set as well. If the TZ variable is not set, localtime attempts to use the time zone information specified in the Date/Time application in Control Panel. **If this information cannot be obtained, PST8PDT, which signifies the Pacific Time Zone, is used by default.**

Why could the localtime method not obtain the time zone information of the server?

I have a native application running as a service on a Windows 2016 Server. The time zone set is Easter Time Zone. But localtime uses Pacific Time Zone.

Comment: Are you using US/Eastern time zone?

Comment: I suspect you'll have to step into it and debug it to find out why not. Oddly I can't find localtime in the CRT source installed with VS2017 :-/

Comment: @LethalProgrammer - Yes US/Eastern time zone

Comment: @Rup - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/localtime-localtime32-localtime64 - 2017 documentation has localtime reference

Comment: I meant the source code of the localtime function itself, so we can see how it's trying to read the time zone from your control panel settings (which I guess means the registry, or some other Windows API call) and presumably failing to. (It looks like it's now part of the Windows 10 SDK instead, which I've somehow installed without CRT source.)

Comment: If you install the Windows 10 SDK, you'll find the source in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\time\tzset.cpp (or a different version component) tzset_from_system_nolock. This calls [`GetTimeZoneInformation(&tz_info)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then takes `tz_info.Bias` and `tz_info.StandardBias`. So I'd guess that the GetTimeZoneInformation call is failing, which you could test separately and check the GetLastError.